# Is there any way that I can navigate to a marker with params from another page (React-Native)?

Tags: javascript, react-native, parameters, navigation, marker

I have a List with markers on a page and I want to navigate to the marker on the map, when I click on a button.

This is a short version of the list.js:

```
export default class List extends Component {

    render() {

        const markerOneLocation = {
            latitude: 52.587374, 
            longitude: 5.137634,
            latitudeDelta: 0.3,
            longitudeDelta: 0.3,
       };

       const showMarkerOne = () => {
           this.props.navigation.navigate('Map', 
           {initialLocation: markerOneLocation});
       }; 

       return (
           <Text onPress={this.toggle}>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 15}} onPress= 
              {showMarkerOne} title='Marker1'> Marker 1 </Text>
           </Text>
       )
   }
}
```

This is a short version of the map.js:

```
   export default class Map extends Component {

       render() {
           return(
              <MapView
                style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                region={{
                    latitude: 52.100748,
                    longitude: 5.646090,
                    latitudeDelta: 4,
                    longitudeDelta: 4,
                }}
              >
                <Marker
                  coordinate={{
                    latitude: 52.474772,
                    longitude: 5.197672
                  }}
                  anchor={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.5 }}
                >
                  <Image
                    source={require('../src/
                           logo_noshadow.png')}
                    style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                  />
                </Marker>
              </MapView>
          )
      }
  }
```

so when I click the button to go to the map. I want the map to navigate to the marker and show it in the center of it.

I tried by adding a markerId as a param, but I don't know how to add it to the marker.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

On the MapView you can set a reference.
In a hook based approach that would look something like:

```
const mapRef = React.useRef(null);

<MapView
    ref={mapRef}
    ... the rest of your settings
/>
```

I see you use a class based approach, but refs are available there as well.
Then on that reference you will have a method called `fitToSuppliedMarkers`.
As it's first parameter it takes an array of `marker identifiers` and when called it will focus the map to the markers that fit the provided list.

```
mapRef.current.fitToSuppliedMarkers([ArrayContaingMarkersIdentifiers], {
    animated: true,
    edgePadding: {
        top: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 50,
    },
});
```

https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods

For this to work you need to add a unique `identifier` to each `<Marker />`

https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md

I see you use a class based approach, but refs are available there as well.